# Disproving the converse of Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Fermat's Little Theorem states that

> If $p$ is a prime and $a \in Z$ with $gcd(a,p)=1$ then $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$

from this I take to the converse to be the statement that

> if $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$ then $p$ is prime and $gcd(a,p)=1$

Taking the result stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2757519/let-n-6t112t118t1-show-that-an-1-equiv-1-pmod-n-if-a-n-1) as a given, I make the claim that taking $p=(6t+1)(12t+1)(18t+1)$ for $t \in N$ disproves this because we have that $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$ and yet $p$ is clearly not prime.

Is this a sufficient proof? I was informed that this answer was not sufficient in an assignment and I can't understand why?

Comment: If you have proof that the particular $p$ you chose results in the stated congruence then yes, it is sufficient.  Separately, a single counterexample is also considered sufficient.  The giver of the assignment would have to clarify why your answer is insufficient.

Comment: This answer is not appropriate, because an easy counterexample is expected, which you can justify yourself without copying Carmichael numbers (exactly what "lulu" says below in a better wording than mine :))

Comment: I would guess that the problem was that you quoted an unfamiliar result.  And you can easily dodge that problem by giving an explicit example.

Comment: I think, you do not even need a Carmichael number. $2^{340}\equiv 1\mod 341$ would already qualify as a counterexample, unless you want to show that even if the congruence holds for all $a$ coprime to $p$ , $p$ need not be prime. Anyway, this is not a "not sufficient proof", whether it has a suitable level, is another story.

Comment: @lulu the previous question asked to prove that result so it's safe to assume we were supposed to use it somehow :)

Comment: Note that there are ways to formulate little Fermat so that its converse is true, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26145/242)